# Error Adding values to pickslist on apex with metadata

Tags: apex, metadata-api, picklist

i'm trying to add a new value to a picklist every time a trigger is executed, but now i'm stuck in front of a wall that i can't pass through due to the fact that i don't understand why i'm getting this error.

> First error: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: '' is not valid for type xsd:boolean, should be '0', '1', 'true' or 'false' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=

The error shows up on the last line of the class, on the upsertResult (I've also tried Update and doesn't work neither, I keep getting the same error)

i Copy also my Apex class and the trigger.
Trigger:

```
trigger test on Maestros__c (after insert) {
System.debug('Llamo a actuar');
testerino.actuar(UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

}

Apex Class:

```
public class Testerino {
@future(callout=true) public static  void actuar(String UserID) {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService(UserID);
    MetadataService.CustomField customField =
    (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField',
    new String[] { 'Account.picklist__c' }).getRecords()[0];
    System.debug('He cogido el valor de customfieldcorrectamente');
    System.debug(customField);
    MetadataService.Picklist picklist = customField.picklist;
    List <MetadataService.PicklistValue> picklistValues = picklist.picklistValues;
    MetadataService.PicklistValue picklistvaluenuevo = new MetadataService.PicklistValue ();
    picklistvaluenuevo.fullName = 'TEST';
    System.debug(picklistValues);
    picklistValues.add(picklistvaluenuevo);
    picklist.picklistValues = picklistValues;
    customField.picklist = picklist;
    System.debug(picklist);
    MetadataService.UpsertResult[] results = service.UpsertMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata [] {customField});
}
```

}

I would like just to know if this is just possible and I can add new values to my pickslist or not. If also someone can see if it's possible what am I missing that would be really nice, but i mainly just want to know if this is possible.
The metadata Classes were downloaded from https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi. And copied into the project ( i only modified 1 thing, added 1 creator class MetadataServiceExamples.createService(UserID), so i could pass it the UserID i got on the trigger (I do this because you can't get the UserID on @future methods.

Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just miss one line

> `picklistvaluenuevo.default_x=false ;`

```
public class Testerino {
@future(callout=true) public static  void actuar(String UserID) {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService(UserID);
    MetadataService.CustomField customField =
    (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField',
    new String[] { 'Account.picklist__c' }).getRecords()[0];
    System.debug('He cogido el valor de customfieldcorrectamente');
    System.debug(customField);

    MetadataService.Picklist picklist = customField.picklist;
    List <MetadataService.PicklistValue> picklistValues = picklist.picklistValues;
    MetadataService.PicklistValue picklistvaluenuevo = new MetadataService.PicklistValue ();
    picklistvaluenuevo.fullName = 'TEST';
    picklistvaluenuevo.default_x=false ;
    picklistValues.add(picklistvaluenuevo);
    picklist.picklistValues = picklistValues;
    customField.picklist = picklist;

    MetadataService.UpsertResult[] results = service.UpsertMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata [] {customField});
}
```

I think this might be usefull for you if i am wrong then correct me.

Comment: It Worked!  I would never had realized that line of code missing by miself, actually made a lot of sense since it need a boolean value, but didn't knew a picklist value needs a default boolean. That was the key part.

Thank you really much. Really apreciated.